# Only some computers can access local apache server some of the time (windows 11)

Tags: apache, server, configuration, django

I've set up an apache server with a Django app and followed all the configuration steps to make it accessible on my LAN. In my office there are about 15 computers. We're all on that same WiFi network. IT says that it's a problem with my setup, not a network problem, but I can't think of anything that would allow connection some of the time and not others. When the other computer can't connect, it does not show anything in my apache access log, nor error log.

If I sign onto the WiFi on my phone, sometimes I can access the server. If I turn off the WiFi and turn it back on, sometimes the server will connect, other times it will not. If I wait a few hours sometimes it'll work again.

Other computers never turn off the wifi, and will lose the ability to connect.

I access it through typing my 192.168.2.xxx:8000 address and can connect every time on my computer. I have a static IP address from IT and have confirmed it is not changing.

Some things I have double checked from other questions:

I disabled my firewall completely (just to eliminate it as a source of the error, though I added rules to allow traffic through)

I am listening on port :8000 and added my IP to the apache listening configuration

my allowed hosts in settings.py is current ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"] though when I had it set to my internal IP it also worked sporadically

Every day I come in and different computers can access it and other cannot. I cannot understand why.

Comment: What is the exact error you get when it fails to work?

Comment: "I access it through typing my 192.168.2.xxx:8000 address" - And that is how everyone else accesses it? You're not using a hostname? (I was going to suggest a DNS issue, ie. settings of primary/secondary DNS servers on the machines/router - but if you're not using a hostname at all then I can't see that that would be an issue.)

Comment: The error is just a standard ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE. There are no server errors or access attempts in the apache logs which makes me think it's something to do with the network/router settings, but IT insists there's nothing that would only do that some of the time. And No, I'm not using a hostname, only accessing through the IP:port

Comment: What network settings (including IP address) do these devices have?  What do `ping` and `traceroute` from these devices to your IP address show?